# Android soft keyboard covers edittext in case of dynamically added layout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

```
<activity
        android:name=".UI.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Above code in activity tag (manifest) works well for activity layout and dialogs. But when I add form layout dynamically to a layout, then at that layout, edittext remains under soft keyboard.

MAIN LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_authentication"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/girl_running_background">

   //Main Layout Code here (Form and stuffs)
</RelativeLayout>
```

Dynamically to be added layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sponsorDetailLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Method to add dynamic layout on main layout.

```
private void signUpDialog() {
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.signup_view, authenticationRelativeLayout, false);//authentication 
    signUpLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.signUpLinearLayout);
    fullNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_Name);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_Password);
    emailEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_Email);

    view.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //Layout added here to main layout
    authenticationRelativeLayout.addView(view);

}
```

Comment: Did you try to have the layout static (not dynamic) and see if the keyboard still blocks the edittext?

Comment: If I used static layout then keyboard doesnot block edittext. But I need dynamic layout.

Comment: Have you try to use 'adjustResize' instead of 'adjustPan' ?